# Using a std::stringstream from static member function for simplicity

Tags: c++, std, stringstream

I need an interface to write short messages to a log file, the messages often contains multiple parts such as an identifier together with a value.

In order to do this I've created a class that handles a lot of minor stuff such as creating filenames with timestamps and so on, although I don't want to use a variable argument list `(int nargs, ...)`, so I thought my best option was to pass a `std::stringstream` to the write function instead.

I want to be able to write these calls as one-liners and not having to create a `std::stringstream` every time I need to do this, therefore I created a static member function to return a stringstream object I could use with my write function, although for some reason it doesn't work.

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass {
public:

    static std::stringstream& stream();
    void write(std::ostream& datastream);

private:

    static std::stringstream* _stringstream;

};
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
std::stringstream* MyClass::_stringstream = new std::stringstream();

std::stringstream& MyClass::stream() {
    MyClass::_stringstream->str(std::string());
    return *MyClass::_stringstream;
}

void MyClass::write(std::string data) {
    this->_fhandle << data << std::endl;
}

void MyClass::write(std::ostream& datastream) {
    std::string data = dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&>(datastream).str();
    this->write(data);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
MyClass* info = new MyClass();
info->write("Hello, world");
info->write(MyClass::stream() << "Lorem" << ", " << "ipsum");
info->write(MyClass::stream() << "dolor sit" << " amet");
```

The code compiles, but when executing the application I get a `std::bad_cast` exception...

Comment: What's wrong with creating a `stringstream` each time you log? How many times per second do you log?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are creating an `std::stringstream`, which
doesn't derive from an `std::ostringstream`.  Just create an
`std::ostringstream`, and the `bad_cast` should disappear.

Having said that, reusing the `std::ostringstream` many times
like this is generally not a good idea; the iostream classes are
full of state, which will not be reset between each use.  It's
better to create new instance each time.  (The classical
solution for this sort of thing is to create a copiable wrapper
class, which forwards to an `std::ostream`.  An instance of this
is returned by `info->write()`, so you can write `info->write() << "Hello, world" ...`.)